# figcaps and page breaks

Tags: floats, page-breaking, endfloat

I'm using [`figcaps`](http://www.mps.mpg.de/software/latex/localtex/preprint/figcaps.sty) to place floats at the end of an article prior to copyediting.  The journal asks for each figure/table on a separate page.  But `figcaps` puts as many figures as possible on each page.  How do I override this? (Not even ugly manual hacks, like inserting `\newpage` at the start or end of the `figure`/`table` environment, work).

If you compile the MWE below, you'll see that both figures are located on p3, not on subsequent, separate pages.

(I've tried using `endfloat` but I get error messages that suggest adverse interactions.  Fixing these may take some work, so I'd rather get `figcaps` to work if possible.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{figcaps}
\printfigures
\figmarkon

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
    \caption{A floating figure}
    \label{float}
\medskip \em \footnotesize \lipsum[1]
\end{figure}

Check out figure \ref{float}.

\lipsum [2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The boxhandler package has a deferral mechanism, a `\holdFigures` command that allows figures created in the document not to be printed until you issue a `\clearFigures` (in your case, at the end of the document) where they are printed one per page (as in journal-submission format).  The only perceived downside is that it uses a macro format, rather than en environment format for defining the figures.  An alternative for output is `\nextFigure[]`, which prints (one by one) the oldest figure on hold, using the optional argument to lay it out as you see fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patch the `\@figurepage` command that's responsible for printing the figures; the usual setting is to leave 20pt of vertical space, which we can change to `\clearpage`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{figcaps}
\printfigures
\figmarkon
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@figurepage}{\vspace{20pt}}{\clearpage}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
    \caption{A floating figure}
    \label{float}
\medskip \em \footnotesize \lipsum[1]
\end{figure}

Check out figure \ref{float}.

\lipsum [2]

\begin{figure}
    \caption{A floating figure}
    \label{float2}
\medskip \em \footnotesize \lipsum[1]
\end{figure}

Check out figure \ref{float2}.

\lipsum [2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks egreg.  In case anyone needs it, the analogous fix for getting tables onto separate pages is `\patchcmd{\@tablepage}{\bigskip}{\clearpage}{}{}`.  Both this patch and yours sometimes generate a blank page (before a full-page table or figure; I can't recreate the effect in a MWE though).  It's not a major concern, but let me know if it's fixable.

Comment: @DanielHarbour `figcaps` puts the contents of a `figure` environment inside a `\vbox`. Don't use objects higher than the page height.

Comment: All clear.  I had to change the textbox dimensions for the copyeditor.  That's what triggered the problem.